# expected expression before ' '

Tags: c, structure, typedef

**file.h**

```
typedef struct xyz{
    unsigned int a;
    }__attribute__ ((packed,aligned(1))) abc,*ptr;
```

**file.c**

```
volatile unsigned int *add;
 add = &abc;
```

> ERROR : Expected Expression before 'abc'

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to take an address of a type, not a variable. `&` doesn't make much sense with typenames.

`abc` is a typename, not a variable. The compiler is telling you that if you use `&` then it is expecting to see a variable name next to it so that it can indeed take it's address.

If I understood your intentions correctly, in file.c you can try something like this:

```
abc variable;
volatile unsigned int *add;
add = &variable;
```

Comment: @nisarg does not know how to because he still has to read the introductory [tour]...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to declare variables at the same time as defining a type. Keep them separate:

```
typedef struct xyz{
    unsigned int a;
} abc_t;

abc_t* ptr;
```

Also `__attribute__ ((packed,aligned(1)))` is not standard C, so you have to ensure that your compile is set to compile non-standard code.

(In gcc this is done by calling the program without the -std parameter, it will by default be a non-standard C compiler)

Comment: Of course it "makes sense", if you never need to refer to the variable's type, for instance.

Comment: @unwind If you never need to refer to the type, then why use typedef in the first place and not just a plain struct? That does indeed not make sense. I don't see why that would prevent you from keeping type definition and variable declarations separate anyhow.

Comment: Right, in the context of a `typedef` it doesn't make sense. I interpreted your answer's first sentence a bit too generally.